# Cannot open "View" dropdown from document library

Tags: document-library, list-view

I am using sp2010. I have a document library. I have created a public view. But When I try to select another view the dropdownbox doesnt open. When I look in the source code I see there is only 1 item in the dropdownbox and thats "All Documents".

This is the dropdownbox which will not be opened!
[image]

These are my views:
[image]

When I add the document library to my homepage and edit the homepage, I can see all the views:
[image]
Other document libraries are working fine. What is going wrong?

Comment: Are you getting any script errors? You should see those if you go to the scripts tab and refresh the page.

Comment: Hi christoffel, I did check for script errors. No erros! I created a new view, removed all the other views, the same issue.